# Twitter api call on multiple tweets using curl

Tags: api, twitter, command

I want to use curl to get some tweet metadata for multiple tweets. Here's the code for one tweet:

```
curl --request GET --url 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids=1376934013013737479&tweet.fields=attachments,author_id,created_at,public_metrics,source' --header 'Authorization: Bearer $BEARER_TOKEN'
```

How can I generalize this for return the metadata for multiple tweets? The tweet ids are stored in a list.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a straightforward matter of adding the other Tweet IDs to the `ids` field, eg

```
curl --request GET --url 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids=1376934013013737479,1377305661378297860,[additional-ids-comma-separated]&tweet.fields=attachments,author_id,created_at,public_metrics,source' --header 'Authorization: Bearer $BEARER_TOKEN'
```

The documentation says that up to 100 IDs can be used in a single request:

> A comma separated list of Tweet IDs. Up to 100 are allowed in a single request. Make sure to not include a space between commas and fields.